# Set color to group of cells in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

Currently we are using following code to set the color in cells,

```
worksheet.Cells[18, 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Constants.highlightingColor);
```

Is there any way to set color to group of cells ? Like we set color in group of elements in  css using class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to set a range of cells at once, you can simply use the `Cells` object indexer overloads.  Something like this:

```
worksheet.Cells[18,1,28,11].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Constants.highlightingColor);
```

Will start at the Cell at row 18 col 1 and go to the Cell at row 28 col 11 and set all background colors.